# Bidirectional event flow in Clean Architecture

Tags: typescript, clean-architecture

In all sources i've found about clean architecture similar event flow is presented:

```
// View (e.g. user clicked a button) => Domain (use case) -> Data (through repository to datasource) -> Server/Db/etc.
```

But for application it may be neccessary to use an events generated by data layer e.g. websocket/event sourcing/FCM/etc.

So if i want to implement such a remote event source i clearly understand it belongs to data layer and it's actually a datasource.

But if i have a hybrid app that uses http together with lets say FCM for some particual cases how can i differentiate a stream datasource i must subscribe to from an http datasource.

E.g. i have a folder structure:

```
    - data
     - datasources
     - repositories
     - mappers
     ...
```

Very simplified http datasource and repo would look like this.

```
    export class PostsRemoteDataSource {
      public async getPostsList(){
        const result = await fetch(/*...*/)
        return result.json()
      }
    }
    // ....
    export class PostsRepository {
      constructor(
        private readonly localDataSource: PostsLocalDataSource,
        private readonly remoteDataSource: PostsRemoteDataSource){}

      public async getPosts(){
        // ...
        const remoteData = await this.remoteDataSource.getPostsList()
        // ...
      }
    }
```

And a stream datasource would look like this:

```
    class PostsRemoteDataSource extends EventListener {
      public connect(someCredentials:any){}
      public sendMessage(message:any){}
      public listen(listener: (data: IPostDTO) => void) {}
    }
```

So i dont understand:

If repository must establish connection and subscribe to such a data source than usecase must subscribe to repository and view subscribes to usecase or repository triggers usecases on datasource event callback or what ?

Maybe that stream data source should belong to some another layer / named differently like Service/PushService/EventBus/something like that to differentiate it from a usual data source ?

I apologize for my english and presentation, it's a bit hard for me to formulate a question like this.

A good example will be a chat app where part of it must uses websocket for messaging and other part is based on http for authentication/loading user preferences/etc.

Comment: You should probably implement the scenario as you described: the use case registers to your data source and pushes the update through presenter to view. I would put these data sources in same layer as regular data sources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After reading some topics and checking examples i think i can stick to that structure - repositories/gateways can return Promise<Data> or Promise<Observable<Data>> stream for usecase to subscribe to data updates. And usecases always return something like Rx Observable which presenter/viewmodel subscribes to but in case of non stream data sourse that observable immediately closes.